# How to load txt file as matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I can load a txt file (which has around 2 million lines) as data frame like this:

```
> a=read.table("Retina_LCL_overlap_readyTPR.txt", header = TRUE)
> head(a)
   chr    pos         gene_id       LCL      Retina       wl      wr
1 chr1 775930 ENSG00000237094 0.3559520 9.72251e-05 31.62278 21.2838
2 chr1 815963 ENSG00000237094 0.2648080 3.85837e-06 31.62278 21.2838
3 chr1 816376 ENSG00000237094 0.3313120 3.85824e-06 31.62278 21.2838
```

But I would like to load it as a matrix to speed up some operation I am doing on this data. I tried doing this:

```
> library(tseries)
> a=read.matrix("Retina_LCL_overlap_readyTPR.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "", skip = 0)
Error in scan(file, sep = sep, skip = skip + 1, quiet = TRUE) : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got 'chr1'
```

I would like my data to look like this after I load it into matrix:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4] 
[1,] 0.3559520 9.72251e-05 31.62278  21.2838  
[2,] 0.2648080 3.85837e-06 31.62278  21.2838   
[3,] 0.3313120 3.85824e-06 31.62278  21.2838
```

Comment: `mat <- as.matrix(data.table::fread("Retina_LCL_overlap_readyTPR.txt", select = 4:7))` uses package `data.table`, is fast and allows you to select the columns of interest.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I realized I can also first do fread my data into "a" and than do: df=data.matrix(a, rownames.force = NA)